# undefined local variable or method `articles_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

undefined local variable or method `articles_path' for #<#:0x39b05f8>
and the code is

```
 <h1>New Article</h1>
  <%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :title %><br>
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
```

Iam new to ruby on rails programming.When i run above code in rails server i got the error as NameError in articles#new.Please give me the answer to resolve the above error.

**Controller Code**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

    def create
        render plain: params[:article].inspect
  end
end
```

**Rake Routes**

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                 Controller#Action
 articles_new GET    /articles/new(.:format)     articles#new
article_index GET    /article(.:format)          article#index
              POST   /article(.:format)          article#create
  new_article GET    /article/new(.:format)      article#new
 edit_article GET    /article/:id/edit(.:format) article#edit
      article GET    /article/:id(.:format)      article#show
              PATCH  /article/:id(.:format)      article#update
              PUT    /article/:id(.:format)      article#update
              DELETE /article/:id(.:format)      article#destroy
         root GET    /                           welcome#index
```

Comment: Post your `controller code` and `rake routes` output.

Comment: There is no method `articles_path` built into Rails. You need to definite it via the appropriate routes.

Comment: In new method add this `@article = Article.new` and try like this `<%= form_for @article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`

Comment: And also show us your `routes`.

Comment: Amy luck with this yet?

Comment: @VenkateshMandadi, there is __no__ way the accepted answer could resolve your issue. Have you actually tried implementing it?

Comment: @VenkateshMandadi, you have selected an incorrect answer and provided no follow-up information. IMO, you should consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and realized it was because my routes.rb had

```
resources :article
```

Just change it to

```
resources :articles
```

and that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here: https://github.com/vmanyushin/rails_getting_started/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L2

It should be resources :articles in routes.rb instead of resource :articles. Note the plural on resource(s).

Answer (score 0):

Restart your server.  That worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

seems like for some reason above your routes file defined the index/create path as `articles_index`, try `articles_index_path`

Comment: I don't know what this was accepted, because this answer is absolute incorrect. According to the `rake routes` output, the `article_index` path very plainly routes to the `articles#index` controller action. The `article#create` action is routed to from an unnamed `POST` route to the `/article` endpoint. The `index` and `create` actions do __not__ reside at the same path.

Comment: I do agree its strange that his rake routes output is as it is because usually the index/create endpoint should only be at `/articles`. However as it stands, it seems that is the way its denoted in the rake routes. "index" and "create" do indeed share a path

Comment: just because the `index` and `create` actions share a common path does not mean they are the same _request_. One is a `GET` request, and the other is a `POST` request. Thus, each is routed independently. You might benefit from learning about [Rails RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: I understand that, what I'm saying is that in the typical manner that a rails resource is defined. The default create/index path would be `/articles` in which if you send a `POST` request to it, would trigger a create action, and if you sent a `GET` request to it, it would trigger an `index` action. What I am saying, is that for some reason (could be he has named his route specifically), this collection route that is typically `articles_path` by default, seems to be renamed to `articles_index_path` as seen in his routes above. I'm quite aware of RESTful conventions, just trying to help out :)

Comment: To the OP - can you paste your routes file for where the articles routes are defined? That may help us figure out why the naming, and default routing seems to be off.